# Images do not show up. UID in URI and construction of URI seems to be wrong

Tags: plone, uid

"Links using UIDs" is activated. Same for "link integrity".

On a few pages images do not show up. The link to images is something like 
`.../datenabgleichtool/resolveuid/4ff237ae-1b26-4854-90cc-892ee84a1ad0/@@images/image/preview`.

When I manually edit the page and reinsert the image in TinyMCE, then this image url changes to `/datenabgleichtool/screenshot_odbc.png/@@images/a96678a5-1fc1-45eb-832e-e24ddecda8da.png`.

What could have happend and how can I correct all pages without manually reinserting images?
Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Short correction hint: Use `plone.app.uuid.utils.uuidToObject` to load the object for the given UID, then replace the `../resolveuid/[UID]` part of the faulty image link with the URL path for the object you located.

Comment: Could you tell us where you open your tinymce ?
* contextual static text portlet editing ?
* edit document content type ?
* group static text portlet editing ?

Comment: This could be a tinymce bug... It should not be linking images this way.

Comment: URL construction and transformation / rendering was OK, but UIDs were not valid, not found in Catalog. My post from above has mixed the saved and the rendered form of the src attribute of img tag.
So there must have been a user action copying the images and deleting the originally linked ones, ignoring the warning of link integrity check.
Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links using UID is a great feature. Plone store "resolveuid/YOURUID" as the path to the object. So you can change the path of this object without updating all your content which use it.

When rendering happens Plone transform theses to real path / URL.

Even if the transform do not happens, URL with resolveuid will work in browser because there is a view or PythonScript which do the redirect.

So if your image do not show up it can be:

- because you have deleted it
- because your current location is weird.
- there is a bug

Comment: Thats interesting to know, that if no transformation happens, there is a script handling these URLs.